# Python image resize and write with same name

Tags: python, opencv

I have a directory of images which I am trying to resize.  However during this process I do not want to retain them in the directory hence I am trying to rewrite with the same name.  The following is my code:

```
import os
from os.path import basename
from imutils import paths
import imutils
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

for (i, imagePath) in enumerate(paths.list_images(args['image'])):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    fil = basename(imagePath)
    filname = os.path.splitext(fil)[0]
    newimage = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
    cv2.imwrite(filname+'.jpg', newimage)
```

When I try to use cv2.imshow for both pre and post resize I could get the display.  Similarly when I print the fil and filname, it gets printed correctly.  However, the images are not getting overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to overwrite them with the exact name and extension they had originally, you don't need to reconstruct the path like you're doing in this line

`filname = os.path.splitext(fil)[0]`

Rather, you can continue to use the variable `imagePath` that was provided with `imutils.paths` which is the exact path to overwrite, already.

`cv2.imwrite(imagePath, newimage)`

---

However, if you do need to take any images of other filetypes and convert them to `.jpg` like you've done, then you will not be overwriting `example.png` when you write `example.jpg`, so you'd need to delete `example.png`.

---

With my changes above, the code overwrites the images with their new sizes on my system.